# Algorithm and R implementation of sparse PCA

Tags: r, pca, sparse

Does anyone know where I can find an algorithm, as well as an `R` implementation of it, to carry out sparse principal component analysis (PCA)?

Comment: Requests for where to find code might be argued not to be directly [on topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). At that link, see the list of topics and the section headed *There are certain subjects that will probably get better responses on our sister sites.* and see if you can either edit your post to make it more clearly on topic, or whether there might be a better location for the question.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for code.

Comment: @NickCox: no because it's a *statistical* code and presumably statisticians are best placed to answer. Please stop this attitude of systematically sending programmers away. It's deeming half the fun of doing stats!

Comment: @user603 I agree with you in general that we do not want to send programmers away as a policy. The problem here is that the question *explicitly* asks just for `R` code. If it were changed to request an *algorithm* I think there would be no controversy.

Comment: @user603 Please consider the explicit policy at http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic and how far the _original_ question matched that. Also, if you want to discuss the principles or change the policy, use Meta. Finally, your reputation, like mine, entitles you to a vote on this; in a mature democracy people should be able to disagree through their votes without rancour. (Most of my activity in statistical science is computational, so I have zero bias against programming.) (I totally agree with whuber above who as usual puts his finger on the key point.)

Comment: For the record, the original version was closed after votes by 4 people, 1 being me. It was then revised and re-opened. It's inaccurate therefore to direct disagreement at me personally; I merely voiced the doubt in the comment above.

Comment: @NickCox: Sorry, I can see my comments was the source of a miss-understanding. I apologize. The second and third sentences were  not meant to address any one user. In general, I think we should edit these kinds of questions  (in the way whuber suggested) ourselves rather than closing them. It's because I think people need more help with formulating a stat question than a programming one (not fair to our community but that's the way I perceive it).

Comment: @user603 Thanks for your comment; I take no offence; I was just underlining facts. I don't know about "in general": in my experience, most poor questions shouldn't be edited to a different question because a good underlying question cannot be identified. But in this case you did edit the question to an acceptable one. Whether it was the OP's real question remains unclear. A side-effect of the edit is that neither of the two up-voted answers, both posted before your edit, really answers the question as it stands! Oh well.

Comment: [pcaPP: Robust PCA by Projection Pursuit](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pcaPP/index.html)

Answer (score 5):

Another good package is the [elasticnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elasticnet/elasticnet.pdf) package that Zou and Hastie put out. It has the function `spca`.

Be careful to select a good value of $\lambda$, the sparsity parameter (or vector of them).

I would be curious to know which package ends up working better for you since the other package mentioned by @Stephan Kolassa is a year newer and is by Hastie's coauthor, Tibshirani.

Answer (score 1):

Which function in which package are you interested in? All code is available on CRAN. For instance, if you are thinking about the [`PMA`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PMA/) package (just the first one I found by googling for "CRAN Sparse Principal Components Analysis"), you can find the source code [here](http://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/PMA_1.0.9.tar.gz).

Comment: Thank you very much for your useful answer.I want to use general form of lasso which elasticnet to select a group of highly correlated variables.if you have any idea which is better please tell me your opinion.